# Trying to understand the space complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

I see a lot of articles online explaining Time complexity but haven't found anything good that explains space complexity well. I was trying to solve the following interview question

> You have two numbers represented by a linked list, where each node
>   contains a single digit. The digits are stored in reverse order, such
>   that the Ts digit is at the head of the list. Write a function that
>   adds the two numbers and returns the sum as a linked list.
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> Input: (7-> 1 -> 6) + (5 -> 9 -> 2).That is, 617 + 295.
>
> Output: 2 -> 1 -> 9.That is, 912.

My solution for it is the following:

```
private Node addLists(Node head1, Node head2) {
    Node summationHead = null;
    Node summationIterator = null;
    int num1 = extractNumber(head1);
    int num2 = extractNumber(head2);
    int sum = num1 + num2;

    StringBuilder strValue = new StringBuilder();
    strValue.append(sum);
    String value = strValue.reverse().toString();
    char[] valueArray = value.toCharArray();
    for (char charValue : valueArray) {
        Node node = createNode(Character.getNumericValue(charValue));
        if (summationHead == null) {
            summationHead = node;
            summationIterator = summationHead;
        } else {
            summationIterator.next = node;
            summationIterator = node;
        }
    }
    return summationHead;
}

private Node createNode(int value) {
    Node node = new Node(value);
    node.element = value;
    node.next = null;
    return node;
}

private int extractNumber(Node head) {
    Node iterator = head;
    StringBuilder strNum = new StringBuilder();

    while (iterator != null) {
        int value = iterator.element;
        strNum.append(value);
        iterator = iterator.next;
    }
    String reversedString = strNum.reverse().toString();
    return Integer.parseInt(reversedString);
}
```

Can someone please deduce the space complexity for this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you even *try* and solve this yourself?

Comment: I would solve it differently: Using recursion, and with a third parameter, telling the algo whether to "carry" a one. So instead of transforming the lists to numbers, adding the number, and transforming the result back to a list, it would work just with lists and single-digit-numbers all the time.

Comment: Sort of unrelated to your question or to making your question better, but: I suspect you were intended to implement the addition yourself...

Comment: Scott Hunter : Thanks for asking..but this is MY solution..and not something I got off the internet.

Comment: tobias_k : Yes I am aware of how to solve it via recursion. But I am specifically trying to understand the concept of space complexity for the solution above vs alternative implementation. But thank you for responding to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The space complexity means "how does the amount of space required to run this algorithm change asymptotically as the inputs get larger"?

So you have two lists of length N and M. The resultant list will have length max(N,M), possibly +1 if there's a carry. But that +1 is a constant, and we don't consider it part of the Big-O as the larger of N or M will dominate.

Also note this algo is pretty straightforward. There's no intermediate calculation requiring larger-than-linear space.

The space complexity is max(N,M).